# What is a sub-resource?

Tags: html, web, mozilla

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState) document.readyState

> Returns "loading" while the document is loading, "interactive" once it
>   is finished parsing but still loading sub-resources, and "complete"
>   once it has loaded.

What specifically constitutes a `sub-resource`? Is a sub-resource limited to other `link` elements to external resources?

(I tried google and MDN and did not find a definition of sub-resource for the web context)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MDN documentation excerpt you cited is coming from the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#resource-metadata-management).

Note that in order to be consistent, the term **sub-resources** should be worded **subresources** (in the original spec. and in MDN).

Even if there is no formal definition of subresources in the HTML5 specification, the term is used later in a way such that you can understand the intended meaning.

> A resource's critical subresources are those that the resource needs to have available to be correctly processed.

To answer your question a subresource is everything that has to be fetched after the html has been parsed like scripts, stylesheets, images, videos, ....